Jenkins cleanWs plugin is not keeping files according to pattern
I have the following configuration for cleanWs in my scripted pipeline JENKINSFILE.
            cleanWs(
                    patterns: [
                            [
                                    pattern: "**/*",
                                    type: "INCLUDE"
                            ],
                            [
                                    pattern: "**/*.txt",
                                    type: "EXCLUDE"
                            ]
                    ]
            )

Expectation:
All files are deleted, but .txt file are kept.
Actual:
All files are deleted.
What do I get wrong?
I switch the order of INCLUDE/EXCLUDE and simplified my pattern to just match .txt files but the files are still deleted :(

Please go through the plugin documentation here.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/
You need to mention only the one pattern. Either exclude or include not both.
The code should look something like this
cleanWs( patterns: [ [ pattern: "**/*.txt", type: "EXCLUDE" ] ] )

This would mean as per documentation that

If there is only an exclude pattern, */ (i.e., delete everything)
will be used as the include pattern, which means that everything will
be deleted except the files matching the exclude pattern.


Having just one pattern does not work, the .txt files are still deleted, as suggested I use the following line of code:
cleanWs(patterns: [[pattern: "**/*.txt", type: "EXCLUDE"]])
